# What happens with repeated transformation of $T(x) =x -1/x$?

Tags: functions

I tested repeated application of $x = x -1/x$ on my computer and could not decide what the long term behavior is.  I iterated up to $500,000$ times and saw variation over a fairly short range from around $-4000$ to $4000$ for starting numbers up to $2,000$.  I realize that limits in the precision of the computer may be a factor. In general, what can be said about the transformation?  Is it an example of chaos?

Comment: Since $T'(x)=1+\frac{1}{x^2}$ the function $T$ is strictly increasing. Therefore you will have $T(x)\approx x$ for large $|x|$.

Comment: @gammatester $T({1 \over 2}) = -{3 \over 2} < {1\over 2}$. $T$ is increasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ and on $(0, +\infty)$, not on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Question on edit: is function $T(x) = x - {1 \over x}$ or $T(x) = {x-1 \over x}$?

Comment: @Mithlesh Upadhyay The content of your edit is dubious (see previous comment), its form is defective as well: please no `\cfrac`, especially in titles.

Comment: I got it, thanks @Did.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I think your edit was wrong. With the equation you set, the relation is periodic with period 3, yet the OP got chaos, which implies the x - (1 / x) interpretation.

Comment: Yes, @ParclyTaxel. :)

Comment: As to me, yes, that's an example of chaos. It has fixed cycles of all sizes, none of them stable.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Yet one detrimental `\cfrac`, please change it.

Comment: @Did, corrected.

Comment: Please disregard this comment.  I asked before I read all the answers. Could someone show me an example of a fixed cycle for this transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few observations

Consider the graph $\displaystyle f(x)=x-\frac{1}{x}$. This can be rewritten as $yx=x^2-1$. Since this the discriminant of this conic is positive, we conclude that this graph is a hyperbola. We can find the asymptotes of this hyperbola by considering very large $x$ or very large $y$. In both cases, the $-1$ becomes negligible, so our equation beomes $yx=x^2$, which means either $y=x$ or $x=0$. These two lines are the asymptotes of the hyperbola. For $(0,\infty)$, the graph of the hyperbola is below the line $y=x$. For $(-\infty,0)$, the graph of the hyperbola is above the line $y=x$. So, for any positive number, $x$, we have $\displaystyle x-\frac{1}{x}<x$. Similarly, for any negative number, $x$, we have $\displaystyle x-\frac{1}{x}>x$. The function $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{x}$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}/\{0\}$. In other words, $0<x_1<x_2 \implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ and $0>x_1>x_2 \implies f(x_1)>f(x_2)$.

The graph $f(f(x))$ has $4$ asymptotes: $y=x$, $x=1$, $x=-1$, $x=0$

The graph $f(f(f(x)))$ has $8$ asymptotes: $y=x$, $x=1$, $x=-1$, $x=0$, $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, $x=-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, $x=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

In general, $f^n(x)$ has $2^n$ assymptotes.

Let's start with a positive value $n$. We know that $f(n)<n$, so if we keep applying the function, $n$ will keep decreasing, until it turns negative. Once it turns negative, if we keep applying the function, $n$ will increase until it is positive, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score -2):

If this transformation converge for some starting point $x$ we would have:

$T(x) = x \rightarrow x - \frac{1}{x} = x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x} = 0$

But then $x = \pm \infty$.

Thus this transformation must diverge or start oscillating.
Easy oscillation that comes to mind is $\pm x$. Then:

$T(x) = -x \rightarrow x - \frac{1}{x} = -x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x} = 2x$

Leaving us with $x = \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}$.

Question now remains: for what starting points will we "converge" to this 2 step oscillation and for what starting points will we diverge?
Shortly playing around with it makes it look like only way to oscillate is to start with $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}$ but proof of it hasn't arrived in my head yet.

Another point one might want to address: Are there any other oscillations? So far I only handled the case $T(x) = x$ and partially $T(T(x)) = x$, but what about $T^n(x) = x$? Do those cycle exists?

Edit:
Playing around with it some more I found that numerical errors can kick you out of a cycle quite easily, and you are then put on a magical ride.
Note: $T'(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}$ is stricly larger than 1 on R so no point is a stable point, meaning that if you make some numerical error (machine precision for example), you will not converge back to the oscilation you were previously on.

Comment: Solve $x-{1\over x}=\pm{\sqrt2\over2}$ for $x$ and you'll get more points which converge to this 2-step cycle. As for the cycles of other sizes, of course they do exist. Consider $x\approx1.4619022$; that would be a 3-point cycle. Try $x\approx1.98904379$ - that's a 4-point one.

Comment: I don't see why that would be a cycle. Care to explain?

Comment: Look at the graph of T(x). It happens to have a vertical asymptote, and that's a good one: T(x) runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ to the left of it, and then does the same _again_ to the right. What would the graph of T(T(x)) look like? It would have 3 such asymptotes. T(T(T(x))) would have even more, and so on. And between every two asymptotes, $f(x)$ runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so there must be a root of $f(x)=x$. Like I said, there are fixed cycles of all sizes, and none of them is stable.

Comment: I don't understand the discussion about asymptotes, but I see how you can get cycles of length n by solving for T^n(x) = x.  With assistance from WolframAlpha, I found 5 values for 3-cycles, with approximate values of +/-.50771, +/-.77786 and -1.4619.  I don't know if there will necessarily always be real valued solutions.

Comment: Look at [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x+-+1%2Fx+-+1%2F(x+-+1%2Fx)),+plot+x), of $T(T(x))$ and $x$. You can see there are atleast two solutions for which $T(T(x)) = x$. That means there exist atleast 2 $x_0$ for which $T(T(x_0)) = x_0$. Now if we look at [the plot of](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x+-+1%2Fx+-+1%2F(x+-+1%2Fx)+-+1%2F(x+-+1%2Fx+-+1%2F(x-1%2Fx))),+plot+x) $T^3(x)$. It has even more solutions due the fact you add more asymptotes. You can repeat this process to find a cycle of any length.

Comment: Main idea is this: this transformation will never give you the same x as you put in (since $T(x) = x$ has no solutions) and no point of $T(x)$ is stable (meaning that if you are $\epsilon$ from some value you are not necessarily bounded to come closer to this value in next iteration). This means, that every iteration due to machine precision your x will be put on a different cycle over and over again. The solutions will always be real since T is a function from reals to real. Only point that might throw some weirdness into this is starting with $x =1$ as it results with next x equall zero.

Comment: There are quite a few points which lead to $x=1$ after a certain number of steps.